# Hiding the soft keyboard in MonoDroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I've got an Activity with a bunch of EditTexts and a button. When the user clicks the button, an answer based on the input from the EditTexts appears in the caption of the button. In the buttonclick handler I change the focus to the button and the cursor disappears from whatever EditText has the focus, but the soft keyboard remains on the screen. How can I force the soft keyboard to vanish?

```
EditText1.ClearFocus();    
EditText2.ClearFocus();    
EditText3.ClearFocus();
calc_btn.Focusable  =   true;
calc_btn.RequestFocus();
```

I've seen several answers as to how to do this in Java, but I haven't been able to figure out how to translate them to C#.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var inputManager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Jon O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429108/jon-o)'s answer above is perfect. This is how you use it.

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click+= onClick;
        EditText es=FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        es.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs e) => 
        {

            if ( e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done )
            {
                var editText = sender as EditText;
                var inputManager = GetSystemService(InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, 0);
            }

        };
        EditText es1=FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
        es1.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs e) => 
        {
            if ( e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done )
            {
                var editText = sender as EditText;
                var inputManager = GetSystemService(InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, 0);
            }
        };



    }
```

I have used the given methods in above code.I dont want to show the soft keypad for both the textboxs.Its not working,have i written it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.InputMethodServices.InputMethodService.InputMethodImpl.HideSoftInput#) useful to you?

There seems to be a method here:

`public override void HideSoftInput (int flags, Android.OS.ResultReceiver resultReceiver)`

Comment: I'm sure that method would be useful if I could figure out how to call it. This does not yield the method, so it appears not to be implemented directly: Android.InputMethodServices.InputMethodService.InputMethodImpl.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely working solution:

```
using Android.Views.InputMethods;

yourEditTextObject.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs e) => 
        {
            if ( e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done )
            {
                var editText = sender as EditText;
                var inputManager = GetSystemService(InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, 0);
            }
        };
```